# Extract Text from a Specific HTML tag when there are Multiple Similar Tags using Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I want to extract the `Date and Time` alone from a **section of the web page** which looks something like this:

```
<div class = "small-text">
    <span id = "ct100900>
       <span>
          <span id = "ct100100"></span>
       </span>
    </span>
    <small>
        Feb 13, 2017 05:10 PM
    </small>
    <small class = "total-views">
       <span class = "ct7890">900 views</span>
    </small>
    <small class = "dummy"></small>        
</div>
```

All I needed is to extract and print the `date and time alone`,as **`Feb 13, 2017 05:10 PM`** using **`Beautiful Soup and Python3`**. Here's my piece of code:

```
    timeFull = soup.find("div",{"class": "small-text"})
    print(timeFull.text)
```

But on execution, the program prints both **`Feb 13, 2017 05:10 PM`** and **`900 views`**. What should be done to extract the `date and time alone` using BeautifulSoup and Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not known with Soup and had to look in to it. Perhaps this will work?

```
timeFull = soup.find("div",{"class": "small-text"}).find("small", {"class": None})
print(timeFull.text)
```

The problem here is that you select the text of the div with the class "small-text". Because this div has multiple elements, it returns all of them. You need to apply a second filter which gets the date. Because the date is stored in the only small-tag with no class, you could use that combination.